# Android Call New Fragmented Activity in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to call Fragmented Activity  Inside the Navigation Drawer Layout

But when i am use

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

Then error is occur

> The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is
>   not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment)

Please Help Me How i can solve this problem

my fragmented class

```
package com.newmaynard;



  import com.newmaynard.listadapter.AllList;

   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.AbsListView;
  import android.widget.ListView;

  public class AllListItem extends Fragment {

ListView listTalent;
ListView listPresent;

String[] strTalent;
String[] strPrasent;

public AllListItem()
{

}

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alllist, container, false);


    strPrasent= new String[] {"All","Preaparation","Purpose","Personality","Passion","Presence"};
    strTalent= new String[]{"All","Valued","Involved","Development","Inspired"};



    listPresent= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listpresent);
    listTalent= (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listtalant);

    listPresent.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    listTalent.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);


    AllList adapterTalent= new AllList(getActivity(), strTalent);
    listTalent.setAdapter(adapterTalent);

    AllList adapterPresent= new AllList(getActivity(), strPrasent);
    listPresent.setAdapter(adapterPresent);

  return rootView;

}


}
```

my import is

```
import com.newmaynard.listadapter.*;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Comment: can you posts the imports for fragment??. Are you using fragment from the support library??

Comment: i have posted my imports and fragmented class

Comment: @Raghunandan  Please See my updated question and suggest me how i can fix it

Comment: you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: how i can  use ' getSupportFragmentManager() '

Comment: By having the import from the support library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity` then you should use `getSupportFragmentManager()` (that returns `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`) instead of `getFragmentManager()` (which returns `android.app.FragmentManager`).

Replace imports

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

With

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

And then

```
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Assuming your Fragments extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Update:
To use FragmentManager outside of Activity, pass it when creating the object. For example

```
public final class NavDrawer {

    private final FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public NavDrawer(final FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    }

....
```

And if creating NavDrawer from Activity

```
new NavDrawer(getSupportFragmentManager())
```

Comment: thanks for replay   but getting error **The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type NavDrawer**

Comment: @Kuldeep pass the FragmentManager to NavDrawer constructor then.

Comment: I don't have idea how i can pass please suggest me how i can pass  and i updated my all imports and frgments class please see

Comment: @Kuldeep updated the answer. If NavDrawer is your class, pass it to a NavDrawer via constructor.